# Intellj Idea refactoring replace one interface with another

Tags: intellij-idea, refactoring, structural-search

I found 2 similar interfaces. I'd like to replace all usages one interface with another in 1 click (refactoring). Refactoring is more safe due it aware of context change rather than plain regexp replace.

But I cannot find fit refactoring in IntelliJ Idea.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [Structural Search and Replac](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/documentation/ssr.html)e. It is available in Ultimate edition.

Edit > Find > Replace Structurally

> Rationale: Imagine that we have a large source code-base that we need
>   to browse or modify it. For instance, we might want to use a library
>   and find out how it works, or we might need to get acquainted with
>   existing code and to modify it. Yet another example is that a new JDK
>   becomes available and we are keen to see the changes in the standard
>   Java libraries and so on. Conventional tools like find and replace
>   text may not completely address these goals because when we use them,
>   it is easy to find or replace too much or too little. Of course, if
>   someone already knows the source code well, then using the whole words
>   option and regular expressions may help make our find-and-replace
>   queries smarter.
>
> The problem of the conventional approach, even with regular
>   expressions, is that they just do not know anything about the syntax
>   and semantics of the source code we are using. This is why we combined
>   the search-and-replace feature with knowledge about the source code,
>   producing the Structural Search and Replace (SSR) feature.

[image]

SSR is a very powerful feature, I recommend [Basics of working with structural search](http://wiki.jetbrains.net/intellij/Basics_of_working_with_structural_search) tutorial to get started.

Comment: Looks like it's in Community Edition as of version 14. I never figured out how to get it to work back when I was using Ultimate, though. :D